# IIS return 404 error but the files are exist

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

I have a website that implemented with `.net core 2.1` and `angular js`. 
I published this website on windows server that worked with IIS.

The problem is that, sometimes response of http requests for some files or request (the ajax request that called) is **404 error** and sometimes it works correctly and I am sure that file is exists because if the user that faced with error, refresh the page, it will load correctly ! 
I attached a photos that compare same requests.
[image]

---

After many days I have this problem yet. I enabled IIS logs and attach one of xml log file here.

[image]

Comment: This is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: thanks @samwu. can you tell me how can I track them ?

Comment: you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Comment: Hi @samwu. I used your link for fixing the problem but the log is not cleared for me. anyway, I uploaded here and I appreciated that if you can check it
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ilxl6y6ep4nmd6t/AAA-3PqVy55ODzr2tVEYPyUQa?dl=0